# Chaining Fetch Calls React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an application where I have to grab certain data from the Github API. I need to grab the name, url, language and latest tag. Because the latest tag is in a separate url, I need to make another fetch call there to grab that data.

I'm running into a certain amount of errors.

1st being the `typeError cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. I'm sure this is from the fetch call to the tag url where there isn't any data. I'm not really sure how to check if it's undefined. I've tried calling checking to see if the `typeof` data is undefined and so on but still get the error.

2nd problem being my tag url data doesn't show up with the other data. I'm sure I'm chaining the data wrong because when I click the add button it shows up.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: '',
    repos: [],
    favourites: []
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { searchTerm } = this.state

    this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value })

    if (searchTerm.split('').length - 1 === 0) {
      this.setState({ repos: [] })
    }
  }

  findRepos = () => {
    const { searchTerm } = this.state

    // First api call here
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${searchTerm}&per_page=10&access_token=${process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN}
`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        const repos = data.items.map(item => {
          const { id, full_name, html_url, language } = item
          const obj = {
            id,
            full_name,
            html_url, 
            language,
            isFavourite: false
          }

          // Second api call here. I need the data from map to get the tags for the correct repo
          fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${full_name}/tags`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              obj.latest_tag = data[0].name
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

          return obj
        })

        this.setState({ repos })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

render() {
  const { searchTerm, repos, favourites } = this.state

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>My Github Favorites</h1>
      <input 
        type="text"
        placeholder="search for a repo..."
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
        onKeyPress={e => e.key === 'Enter' && this.findRepos()}
      />
      <button 
        type="submit" 
        onClick={this.findRepos}>
        Search
      </button>

     <div className="category-container">
      <div className="labels">
        <h5>Name</h5>
        <h5>Language</h5>
        <h5>Latest Tag</h5>          
      </div>

      // Here I list the data
      {repos.map(repo => (
        <div key={repo.id}>
          <a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.full_name}</a>
          <p>{repo.language}</p>
          {repo.latest_tag ? <p>{repo.latest_tag}</p> : <p>-</p>}
          <button onClick={() => this.addToFavs(repo)}>Add</button>
        </div>
      ))}   

      <h1>Favourites</h1>
      {favourites.map(repo => (
        <div key={repo.id}>
          <a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.full_name}</a>
          <p>{repo.language}</p>
          <p>{repo.latest_tag}</p>
          <button>Remove</button>
        </div>
      ))}   
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}
}

export default App
```

Comment: You're not waiting for the inner `fetch()` to complete before you `return obj`. Use promise chaining and always `return` something from your callbacks. Use `Promise.all` on the array of promises you'll be getting

Comment: use async/await 
`const obj = await fetchFn({searchTerm, REACT_APP_TOKEN}); const response = await secondFetch(obj)`

Comment: @Bergi would you mind writing a quick snippet with your explanation?

Comment: You can check name exists or not and than asign 
`if(data[0] && data[0].name) {obj.latest_tag = data[0].name }`

Comment: @IftekharDani Thanks that fixed my error :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Promise.all(), you could rewrite your code like the following.

```
findRepos = () => {
const { searchTerm } = this.state;

// First api call here
const first = fetch(
  `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${searchTerm}&per_page=10&access_token=${
    process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN
  }`
);
// Second api call here. I need the data from map to get the tags for the correct repo
const second = fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${full_name}/tags`);
Promise.all([first, second])
  .then((res) => Promise.all(res.map(r => r.json())))
  .then([data1, data2] => {
    data1.then((firstData) => {
      /*Do something you want for first.*/
    });
    data2.then((secondData) => {
      /*Do something you want for second.*/
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Is the resolved parameter from Promise.all() an array? `Promise.all([first,second]).then([res1, res2])...`?

Comment: The thing is the second fetch depends on the first one so I need the second fetch inside the first fetch so this won't work unless I'm not thinking straight.

Comment: @stealththeninja No, the parameter after triggered Promise.all is array of promise. You don't need to pass [res1, res2] again. Read here.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @Durian checked this morning right after my comment. See first example in link. I think `[res1, res2]` are objects, not Promises. `res.json()` does return a Promise, though.